# ios reading UFT-8 characters - issue with accents

Tags: ios, utf-8

I have an array with the following data:

```
{
"@id" = 6;
"@name" = "\U00c3\U0089tats-Unis";
"@status" = active;
"@version" = 1;
}
```

If i do `po [[pays objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"@name"]`, i get `Ãtats-Unis`
However, I should be getting `États-Unis`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its correct. Try this instead:

```
{
"@id" = 6;
"@name" = "\U00c9\U0089tats-Unis";
"@status" = active;
"@version" = 1;
}
```

0xC3: http://unicodelookup.com/#Ã/1

0xC9: http://unicodelookup.com/#É/1

Also keep in mind that you have to use an encoding (like `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`) before you display it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I have to use an encoding before display. Using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` fixed it.